# Key-Value Assignment via list comprehension in python

Tags: python, list-comprehension, dictionary-comprehension

For a school assignment, I have to adapt a given code but keep the dictionary comprehension mechanism in Python. 
Given my code

```
dct = {k: v for k in ["HELLO", "SLEEPING"] for v in ["WORLD", "CITY"]}
print(dct["HELLO"])
```

the printout is "CITY". How do I have to adapt the code to get "WORLD" returned?
Thank's a lot!

Comment: `dict(zip(["HELLO", "SLEEPING"],["WORLD", "CITY"]))`?

Answer (score 1):

Use `zip`

```
dct = {k: v for k, v in zip(["HELLO", "SLEEPING"], ["WORLD", "CITY"])}
print(dct["HELLO"])
```

And if you can get rid of the dictionary comprehension:

```
dct = dict(zip(["HELLO", "SLEEPING"], ["WORLD", "CITY"]))
```